# How to write a list of lists to a txt file in python without using pickle or other alternatives?

Tags: list, python-3.x, text-files

Say I have the list of lists:

```
mylist=[[1,3,4],[3,5,6],[9,0,8],[8,6,3],[8,2,5]]
```

Is it possible to write it to a single txt file? I know how I can write it to 5 separate files, but I can't work out how to just write it to one so that I'd be able to read it back in the same form.

I want to achieve this without using pickle or other alternatives.

Comment: did you have any search about this simple task already ?

Comment: yes, there are [other](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) [serialization](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) [options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

Comment: @KasraAD - yes, and I didn't find a solution that suited me.

Comment: do you want to write the list with this shape ? or want to write its elements ?

Comment: Just the elements so I can read it back as a list of lists.

Comment: you have meany choice for this task ! you can concatenate elements with a `,` and write to file. `>>> ','.join(map(str,reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,mylist)))
'1,3,4,3,5,6,9,0,8,8,6,3,8,2,5'
` then write the result to file

Comment: yaml, xml, csv, json, sqlite. Choose what you want. It's not big deal to save each array element to new line ...

Comment: @KasraAD - surely if I do that then when I read it back from the file I won't know where each list starts and ends?

Comment: ahan , so try `>>> '|'.join(''.join(map(str,j)) for j in mylist)
'134|356|908|863|825'` and after read split with `|` . but any way you have meany choice and , JSON is a nicety way for such tasks !

Comment: @Oceanescence you're welcome , but as a friendly advise :) its better to add your code to answer  and say about its problem till ask for an answer ! then you'll get better answers and , dont get downvote on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repr() for every item in the list can be evaluated, as in your example, this works.

```
mylist=[[1,3,4],[3,5,6],[9,0,8],[8,6,3],[8,2,5]]
with open('tem2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(repr(mylist))
with open('tem2.txt') as f:
    list2 = eval(f.read())
print(list2 == mylist)
# True
```

and so does this

```
with open('tem2.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('list2 = ' + repr(mylist))
from tem2 import list2
print(list2 == mylist)
# True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a much easier method by far!